# Robust workflow for catching up with a master branch?

Tags: git

Let's say I am working on a non-trivial feature branch that is following a "master" branch of a project with quite a bit of activity. This routinely leaves me in a situation that for sake of saneness, I have to fall a bit behind the "head" in order to figure out how to make something work.

This often leads to a situation where my branch is a few thousand commits behind the master branch - with all the fun things that entails, such as relevant modules getting refactored or similar. Once I decide to start "catching up" this leaves me with with a tricky task: A monolithic merge is out of question, as:

1. It's practically impossible to consider all "my" changes multiplied by all "master" changes at the same time. The few times I tried this, I made so many mistakes that I eventually had to back out.
2. The resulting merge would be so gigantic that all the magic hidden within it would be quite a documentation nightmare.

As a result, the approach I have ended up with is doing "staged" merges: Instead of merging with master directly, selectively merging with "interesting" points in master's history. This would typically be commits concerning modules that likely have "tricky" conflicts. The great advantage of this is that I have actual buildable intermediate points that I can reason about and test, therefore making the whole process much more manageable.

Yet this approach seems to have downsides... Namely, if there's a mistake in a merge that I only notice later on. I tried using `git rebase -i -p` in order to squash fixes into the history, but found out the hard way that this doesn't seem to be the kind of usage people behind it had envisioned. To be specific

- inserting changes between merges seems to cause the rebase process to bail out with more or less complicated conflicts, and
- squashing a regular commit into a merge commit seems to make the new commit a non-merge, losing the reference to the merged commit

Now I'm halfway towards working around all this using some more or less fancy shell scripting, but I am seriously wondering whether I have just missed some piece of Git functionality that could help me with dealing with this situation. Best idea I could come up with so far is using rerere to redo all the merges manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that rebasing a topic branch onto master proves to be an easier / more manageable process.

So instead of this

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--M
       \         /
        X--Y--Z-
```

do this

```
 A--B--C--D--E--F
                 \
                  X'--Y'--Z'
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)

Answer (score 1):

In a easier way, you are not going to `git merge` (or `git cherry-pick`) any changes FROM master to your feature branch. You ALWAYS `git rebase` your feature branch to move your changes after master.

If you keep git rebase often and keep git rebase small, live will be easier.

Comment: I am aware that being behind is not a good idea - this question is about how to get *out* of it in a structured way. Rebasing the complete distance is just an insane proposition (trust me, I tried - one week of work down the drain). And doing a staged approach with rebases would have me end up with dozens of rebased branch copies - a nightmare if I want to track down where exactly a bug crept in.

Comment: If you want to know WHICH rebase buggy, yes it does not help. But why you need that? 

I have more interest in which COMMIT is buggy, and fix that one.  I don't interest in revisions of rebased branches at all.    I did rebased a six month behind branch in two days, by segment and merge carefully without problem.

Comment: If too much behind, I could suggest you rebase few by few... e.g.
git rebase master~{50} mybranch, followed by git rebase master~{40} mybranch, git rebase master~{30} mybranch ...;  smaller conflict are easier to handle.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with doing it "staged". And no, the "commit" approach wouldn't work well - the complexity isn't understanding my changes, but the changes coming from master. I *need* to be able to "bisect" these bugs down along the master line, or I won't get anywhere. I still think fine-grained merges are the best way to go, even though Git makes it [harder than necessary](http://github.com/scpmw/git/commit/fa112021ab1) to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase` is an amazing feature to work with if done so properly.

I'm not sure if you have tried in your case but what I would do is the following.

Checkout master branch make sure its up to date with origin.
Checkout your feature branch
`git rebase master`

It will pretty much guide you along if there are any conflicts allowing you to fix conflicts as you go and if you run into anything weird you can always do `git rebase --abort`

Say you do run into an issue, you fix the file and do `git add <some file>` then `git rebase --continue` and the rebase will keep doing its job.

Do make sure that if your feature branch has been pushed to the remote and been worked on by others do not use rebase.

Comment: Rebasing doesn't work for two reasons - firstly I have published my feature branch, so I would be killing other people's history. But more critically I have done multiple years of development on this branch, so rebasing all that will be even harder than a merge. I also wouldn't like to lose all that history.